# When I send or post a QMouseEvent, at the position of a QPushbutton, its clicked() signal is not emitted

Tags: qt, button, mouseevent, signals, signals-slots

I try to design a gui for an augmented reality application using the kinect. The idea is, to use the hands detected by the kinect skeleton tracking to control an application via gestures.

This question is not about gestures, as this part of my appilcation works fine.

In my application i want to simulate a mouse click whenever a click gesture is performed. To do this, i am sending two events one, mousebuttonpressed, and one mousebuttonreleased, as a normal click is also a series of press and release.

The whole thing works fine on a QWebView. In the browser window, i can "click" on links.

But for some reason i cannot "click" on a QPushButton. The clicked() signal is not emitted.
I have a short example to illustrate my problem:

First the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QApplication app( argc, argv );
    QWebViewButtons mainapp( 0, Qt::Window );
    app.setActiveWindow( &mainapp );
    mainapp.show();
    mainapp.setApplication( &app ); //this is a setter to also get access to the main application in the widget
    return app.exec();
}
```

This is my own widget:

```
QWebViewButtons::QWebViewButtons(QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags ): QWidget(parent, flags ){
    this->m_ui.setupUi( this );
    QObject::connect( this->m_ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT( buttonClicked(bool) ) );
}

void QWebViewButtons::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* event ){
    printf("mouse click, %d, %d\n", event->pos().x(), event->pos().y() );
}

void QWebViewButtons::buttonClicked( bool clicked ){
    printf("slot button clicked\n");    
}

void QWebViewButtons::keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent* event ){
    printf("Key pressed\n"); 
    QPoint pos( this->width()/2, this->height()/2 );
    QPoint global = this->mapToGlobal(pos);
    QWidget *w = this->m_app->widgetAt(global);
    //printf("widget under point of click: %s", w);
    QApplication::sendEvent( w, new QMouseEvent( QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pos, Qt::MouseButton::LeftButton, Qt::MouseButton::LeftButton, Qt::KeyboardModifier::NoModifier ) );
    QApplication::sendEvent( w, new QMouseEvent( QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, pos, Qt::MouseButton::LeftButton, Qt::MouseButton::LeftButton, Qt::KeyboardModifier::NoModifier ) );
}
```

I followed the suggestion here:
[Qt Artificial mouse clicks doesnt work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451492/qt-artificial-mouse-clicks-doesnt-work-properly)
and send to send my mouse events directly to the QPushButton. But that didn't help.
I also tried to send the mouse events to "this", or the main app.

Now I am running out of ideas.
What I want to have is, that the buttonClicked() slot is called if i press any key. But i only is called if i click the button with my mouse. 
How can i accomplish this? Or is my basic idea completely false?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: so by QWidget *w = this->m_app->widgetAt(global); you know which button has been activated? but can't tell the application that it has been clicked?

Comment: i know which widget is at that position, and then i can check if it is a button, and call the buttons click() function. But this is not what i want, because then i would not need to send mouse events. What i want, is to get the same behaviour as if the left button of the mouse was clicked, and left Qt do the rest, no matter if there was a button or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the trick was to really send the click to the EXACT widget at the desired click position. In my application i had some trouble because of semi transparent widgets lying over each other.

So the widgetAt(global) command wouldnt help me. 
But you can use childAt(global) instead. Of course you need to know from which widget you want to find the child.

That did the trick for me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

So, do I get that right? When doing your "click-gesture" you come into keyPressEvent? If so, you can check whether the "click" has been done above the button and explicitly call the button's clicked() signal. But that's not what you want?

And what exactly is QWebViewButtons? The area the user does his gestures in?

Have you debugged into the keyPressEvent to see if your sendEvent has the correct widget (w)? I can't see why the widget should not recieve the event...

And remember that when new'ing a QMouseEvent and sending it via sendEvent is is never deleted. When using sendEvent you should create your event on the stack.

Maybe you should have a look at this thread, where a QTestEventList is recommended: [Mimicking/faking a Mouse Click and Mouse Wheel using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004254/mimicking-faking-a-mouse-click-and-mouse-wheel-using-qt). But I can imagine that you don't want test functions do the trick ;)

Comment: I think the problem is, that i dont know to which widget/object i should send my click events. In my real application i dont know where the buttons are, as they are positioned via layouts, and even worse. There are several widgets over each other, and some of them are transparent. In this applicaton, when i call the widgetAt function, i dont get the button, even if i click it. It returns one of the other widgets. If i send my mouseevent to that widget, some of them reach my button. But not all. Unfortunately i cant post code here, because thats way too much

Comment: In the application i mentioned in the above comment, i am able to "click" one button via gestures. But when i try to click on another one, always the first one gets the mouseclickevent. Not matter which Button i click with the first click, all subsequent clicks are directed to that one. How do i cause such a behaviour?